# How can I deploy beego app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, beego

I'm creating a web app in *beego* that I need to have running in Heroku.

I can get it running normally if I just specify the binary for the app in the `Procfile`. But I want to have *swagger* available in the app, so I need to use `bee` to start the app like:

`bee run -downdoc=true -gendoc=true`

so that it automatically creates and downloads all the swagger related icons, html, etc.

But, if I specify that as the command in `Procfile` (even after adding *bee* to vendor so that it is available), it fails because the app doesn't have the `go` command available in runtime. The exact error is this:

`0001 There was an error running 'go version' command: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH`

How can I bypass this without adding the whole swagger specification to heroku (and github, since it is a repository)?

Comment: In case anyone cares... I just gave up and am using google cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run `bee` command on heroku, because it is a executable program.

But you can run beego app on heroku with adding project dependencies. In order to that you should use tools like https://github.com/kardianos/govendor.

**1. After install govendor try following steps in your project folder;**

```
$ govendor init
```

This command will create `./vendor/vendor.json` file in current directory.

```
{
  "comment": "https://github.com/ismailakbudak/beego-api-example",
  "heroku": {
    "install" : [ "./..." ],
    "goVersion": "go1.11"
  },
  "ignore": "test",
  "package": [],
  "rootPath": "reporting-api"
}
```

Add `heroku` tag like above example. There is a information about this configuration on heroku docs in here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-dependencies-via-govendor#build-configuration

**2. After this add beego package dependency with this command**

```
$ govendor fetch github.com/astaxie/beego
```

It will download the beego packages to `./vendor` directory

**3. Lastly you should configure listen ports and beego runmode as prod for heroku in `main.go` file**

To deploy your app without problem, default config must be `runmode = prod` in `conf/app.conf`. I tried to set it default as dev and change it from heroku config vars as below, but it compiles packages before the set runmode and gives exception with this message `panic: you are running in dev mode`.

```
func main() {
    log.Println("Env $PORT :", os.Getenv("PORT"))
    if os.Getenv("PORT") != "" {
        port, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("PORT"))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            log.Fatal("$PORT must be set")
        }
        log.Println("port : ", port)
        beego.BConfig.Listen.HTTPPort = port
        beego.BConfig.Listen.HTTPSPort = port
    }
    if os.Getenv("BEEGO_ENV") != "" {
        log.Println("Env $BEEGO_ENV :", os.Getenv("BEEGO_ENV"))
        beego.BConfig.RunMode = os.Getenv("BEEGO_ENV")
    }

    beego.BConfig.WebConfig.DirectoryIndex = true
    beego.BConfig.WebConfig.StaticDir["/"] = "swagger"

    beego.Run()
}
```

You can use `BEEGO_ENV=dev bee run` to continue develop your app without change it again